# How to interpret pairplots()

Tags: distributions, classification, data-visualization, scikit-learn, data-preprocessing

I have been working on a Classification problem. And I want to see how many features associate with the target variables.
Let me share an example. I got this pairplot using

```
target = 'Occupancy'
sns.pairplot(df, hue=target)
plt.show()
```

A bit of data's background: This data is about predicting room's occupancy (occupied/unoccupied). It is a classification problem.

Here is the pairplot:
[image]

My questions are:

1. How to do I interpret this? Specially, to find which features are the strongest predictors.
2. For example, if we see `Temperature` to `Light` (third subplot in the first row), it can be seen through the **hue** that its a really good distinction drawn in this association. should I consider it as that both these features (in a combination) are great predictors?
3. Is there a way to view such associations with only one feature to target? (Like here, we have a pair of features to the target)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pair plot is really just a scatter plot between all combinations of two variables in your dataset. This means you can essentially ignore one of the two triangles (the lower half is the same as the upper half with the axes swapped) and the diagonal would be a perfect 45° line if you'd plot the variable against itself, so that's usually replaced by a histogram.

> How do I interpret this?

Just like any other scatter plot; it shows how values of one variable relate to values of another. For example, you see there is almost perfect correlation between `Humidity` and `HumidityRatio` (gee, I wonder why?) as the points create an almost perfect line. There seems to be very little correlation between `Humidity` and `Temperature` however (e.g. it's not because one is low that the other also tends to take a certain value). An in-between case might be `CO2` and `HumidityRatio`, where you see that high values in one tend to associate with high values in the other, but not unequivocally so.

> Should I consider that both `Temperature` and `Light` (in a combination) are great predictors?

Possibly, but not necessarily. While it is true that your outcome, shown as blue/orange, shows a clear pattern versus `Light` (the x-axis in the third plot on the first row), the split between these colors on the y-axis (`Temperature`) is a bit less convincing. However, what you can also see is that `Light` and `Temperature` are not strongly correlated, so including both of these in a model will not cause issues (collinearity).

If you were to include both the highly correlated `Humidity` and `HumidityRatio`, either of these variables would tell you almost all that's explained by the other, which will lead to issues in model fitting.

There are many other things that you can glean from these scatter plots, for example:

- `cat_part_of_day` is perfectly correlated with `Hour` (minus a shift), it seems like the former is 1 for hours 8-20 thereabouts. There's no reason to include both of these in a model.
- There are similarly high correlations between (shifted) `Hour`, `Temperature`, `Light`, and your outcome. `cat_part_of_day` being 0 is pretty much a perfect predictor of lower temperatures, the light being off (?), and no occupancy.

> Is there a way to view such associations with only one feature to target?

This is probably the question that should've come before creating this (apparently confusing) pair plot. One option would be to make scatter plots of your outcome versus each variable individually. Another option is already shown in your very plot: the diagonal has empirical densities of each variable by outcome.

In these density curves you'd essentially be trying to draw a vertical line so that you divide as much of the colors on each side. `Light` is a near-perfect example: if this is about >300 you're almost certain of occupancy (all orange is on the right), otherwise almost certainly not (all blue is on the left). As already mentioned `Hours` (shifted) and `cat_part_of_day` can also near-perfectly predict non-occupancy. `Temperature` is an intermediate case where ~21 divides your outcome in less vs. more occupancy, but the separation is not as distinct. `Humidity` is maybe the best example of a poor predictor on its own: there's no point where the two densities really separate.

There is some scaling going on there which I don't really understand and which betrays an issue with your scatter plots: some points seem to have a *lot* of samples overplotted whereas others don't. Looking at `CO2` and `Light` for example, the low values in these variables (showing up as a single line in the scatter plots) seem to make up >80% of your sample. Another argument for looking at the densities.

**In summary**, I would approach your problem by first checking the relationship of each individual variable versus the outcome, which you can do here by the density curves on the diagonal. Then, check the correlation between candidate predictors: as mentioned, it makes no sense to include both `Humidity` and `HumidityRatio` or `Hours` and `cat_part_of_day`: these variables contain much of the same information. Finally, something to keep in mind is that only a model can give you conditional estimates: it might very well be that e.g. `Humidity` is not a good predictor in and of itself, but it might add a lot of still-missing information if you also know what `Temperature` and `CO2` are!

Comment: Thank you for such wonderful insights. So here, is it correct to say that each plot takes two variables's distributions (ignoring rest) and just sprinkle targets as hue?
If that is correct, then does it make this plot an ideal candidate for choosing only a couple of features to predict?
Let me elaborate. Suppose if i had found a pair that clearly distinguished the classes, I should had picked it right away, ignoring all others and do a logistic regression on it?

Comment: Each plot shows essentially 3 dimensions: the two variables on the X/Y axes, and the outcome as colour. They provide hints as to which variables are strong predictors (examples include `Light` and `cat_part_of_day` where the outcome occurs almost exclusively for certain values of these variables) and which variables are strongly correlated. Interesting features ideally show a clear pattern versus the outcome and do not correlate strongly with one another. There might still be higher-order interactions that a model can show you more clearly though, so I wouldn't outright ignore the rest.